# Need to Initialize new instance of object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, codedom

The following code:

```
        CodeVariableDeclarationStatement variableDeclaration = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(
            // Type of the variable to declare.
            typeof(string),
            // Name of the variable to declare.
            "TestString");
```

Produces the following VB.Net Statement:

```
Dim TestString As String
```

What change would I need to make for it to look like this:

```
Dim TestString As New StringBuilder()
```

I'm interested in how to get that NEW keyword to appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `CodeObjectCreateExpression` as a 3rd argument in the constructor:

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement variableDeclaration = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(
    // Type of the variable to declare.
    typeof(System.Text.StringBuilder),
    // Name of the variable to declare.
    "TestString",
    // A CodeExpression that indicates the initialization expression for the variable.
    new CodeObjectCreateExpression( typeof(System.Text.StringBuilder), new CodeExpression[] {} )
);
```